# How to make:folder in folder in folder... to the infinity in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I need to make the option that in folder you can create new folder,then a new folder inside the new folder... and so on indefinitely. Like we can do it on a desktop.
I can't find anything similar in the documentation.
I'm wondering if I can have a relation in Folder Model:

```
public function folder()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Folder::class);
}

public function folders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Folder::class);
}
```

and does this work at all?

I'm also wondering, what would a table for folders in a database look like?
Can we have:

```
 $table->unsignedBigInteger('folder_id');
            $table->foreign('folder_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('folder')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Also, I have to do everything on the API route, so I'm wondering, how I can add `/folder/{folder}` every time I create new folder?

Comment: I am just curious, did you migrate & it worked?

Comment: I haven't done anything yet.
 I wonder if my logic is good and if these things can be done in laravel

Comment: Follow this https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-recursive-hasmany-relationship-with-unlimited-subcategories/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are showing is defining a 1 to many relationship between a folder. This should be enough, since a folder may only have 1 parent folder. I would recommend the following relationship naming:

```
public function parentFolder()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Folder::class);
}

public function childFolders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Folder::class);
}
```

The route will be a bit more tricky though:

```
Route::get('/folder/{folder}', function ($folder) {
   $hierarchy = explode('/', $folder);
   $root = array_shift($hierarchy);
   $currentFolder = Folder::where('name', $root)->doesntHave('parentFolder')->firstOrFail(); // Root folder has no parents
   while (!empty($hierarchy)) {
       $currentFolder = Folder::where('name', array_shift($hierarchy))
                 ->whereHas('parentFolder', function ($q) use ($currentFolder) { 
                       $q->where('id', $currentFolder->id); 
                  })->firstOrFail(); 
   }
   // $currentFolder should be the correct folder
   
   
})->where([ 'folder' => '.*' ]); // {folder} can be any string
```

If you want to simulate a Linux like system you can always modify the above to add a folder named `/` as the root of all folders. This will require you to get this folder first before looping through to get the directory structure